# Query users with 6 order days in the last 4 months from Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an order index in our elastic search.
The data is as follows
{
"id":"value",
"user_id":"value",
"created_at":"2021-06-07T07:36:02.000Z"
.....
}

A user can order more than once in a day.

I want to fetch all the users who have greater than 6 order days in the last 4 months.

I need help with this query?

Comment: You should research first.

Comment: @Coder welcome to the Stackoverflow, please explain more with sample data, and your expected results, also what have you tried?